# settimeout and wait if timeout already set

Tags: javascript, queue, settimeout

How to create queue for settimeout function.

I want to create function with settimeout to print console after 2 second and but if the same settimeout is already in waiting to execute, new timeout function should be execute after complete first one

```
<script>
function print_console(text,time)
{
   if(timeout is not already set)
   {
      timeout=setTimeout(function(){console.log(text);},time);
   }
   else
   {
     time=addition of time of already setted timeout + argument time
     timeout=setTimeout(function(){console.log(text);},time);
   }
}
print_console('i will print in 1000 minisec',1000);
print_console('i will print in 3000 minisec',2000);
print_console('i will print in 6500 minisec',3500);
.................
.............
</script>
```

I expect the output for this function on console output screen--

i will print in 1000 minisec  ---   07/08/2019 04:01:01

i will print in 3000 minisec  ---   07/08/2019 04:01:03

i will print in 6500 minisec  ---   07/08/2019 04:01:06

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of `async/await` for this:

```js
(async () => { 
  async function print_console(text,time) {
    await new Promise((res, rej) => {
      setTimeout(() => (console.log(text), res()), time);
    });
  }

  await print_console('i will print in 1000 minisec',1000);
  await print_console('i will print in 3000 minisec',2000);
  await print_console('i will print in 6500 minisec',3500);
})();
```

---

Edit: OP wants to call it outside this scope. Then I'd use another approach, using an IFEE to store an array, a flag var and a function caller into function scope:

```js
const print_console = (() => {
  const arr = [];
  let isProcessing = false;
  
  setInterval(() => {
    if(isProcessing) return;
    
    const next = arr.shift();
    if(next) {
      isProcessing = true;
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(next.text);
        isProcessing = false;
      }, next.time);
    }
  });
  
  return (text, time) => {
      arr.push({text, time});
  } 
})();


print_console('i will print in 1000 minisec',1000);
print_console('i will print in 3000 minisec',2000);
print_console('i will print in 6500 minisec',3500);
```

Comment: But sir i want to call print_console() from outside

Comment: @HarendraChauhan oh I didn't know that. I've just updated my post suggesting another approach. ;)

Comment: Thanks you very much sir for your quick reply and solving my problem.

Comment: @HarendraChauhan great! You can either upvote this answer if you found this helpful :)

Comment: I am here afer 5 month, your program is awesome and working properly but when i execute this in Internet Explorer, it's not working. can you recheck your program and test it in IE11.

Comment: @HChauhan, does it throw any error? Unfortunatly, I don't have any Windows to test it with.

Comment: No, its not throwing any error but no other function is working in same javascript file in which i define it.

I also Try to change `const print_console = (() => {` this line to `const print_console = (function() => {` but no solution found.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the additional calls into queue and then process it at the end of timer:

```
var print_console_stack = [], print_console_timeout = null;

function print_console(text,time)
{
   if(!print_console_timeout)
   {
      print_console_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
          console.log(text);
          print_console_timeout = null; //reset this timeout

          var next = print_console_stack.shift();
          if (next) {
              print_console(next.text, next.time);
          }
      }, time);
   }
   else
   {
     print_console_stack.push({text: text, time: time});
   }
}
print_console('i will print in 1000 millisec',1000);
print_console('i will print in 3000 millisec',2000);
print_console('i will print in 6500 millisec',3500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
function print_console(text,time){
  var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(text);
      resolve()
    }, time);
  });
  return p;
}

print_console('i will print in 1000 minisec',1000).then(function() {
  return print_console('i will print in 3000 minisec',2000);
}).then(function() {
  return print_console('i will print in 6500 minisec',3500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a queue of functions were each function will execute a `setTimeout`. Then, when a `setTimeout` is performed, you can get the next function of the queue an executed.

Follows a full working example:

```js
var timeQueue = [];
function onClick() {
  print_console(`The button was clicked!`, 2000);
}

function printALot() {
   print_console(`Row 1!`, 2000);
   print_console(`Row 2!`, 5000);
   print_console(`Row 3!`, 300);
   print_console(`Row 4!`, 400);
   print_console(`Row 5!`, 2000);
   print_console(`Row 6!`, 3000);
   print_console(`Row 7!`, 400);
   print_console(`Row 8!`, 3000);
   print_console(`Row 9!`, 400);
}

function print_console(text, time) {

  let localTime = time;
  let functionToExecute = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(text);
      timeQueue.pop();
      execute_next_print_console();
    }, localTime);
  }
  timeQueue.push(functionToExecute);
  if(timeQueue.length === 1) {
   execute_next_print_console();
  }
 
}

function execute_next_print_console() {
  if(timeQueue.length > 0) {
    let functionToExecute = timeQueue[0];
    functionToExecute();
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="onClick()">click me!!!!</button>
<button onclick="printALot()">Print a lot!</button>
```